# Grouping multiple dataframes into one, with one column as colnames and another as index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dataframes each of which is in the following format:

```
           id                 time      prob
392  13619782  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.149796
393  12926892  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.025866
394  12585081  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.031470
395  10445552  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.511263
396    360761  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.030153
397  17162003  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.068670
398  11387266  2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.182782
```

The time column does not vary within each dataframe and the id column is the same list from dataframe to dataframe i.e. the next dataframe looks like this:

```
           id                 time      prob
413  13619782  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.171445
414  12926892  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.024932
415  12585081  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.030125
416  10445552  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.504263
417    360761  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.027320
418  17162003  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.062276
419  11387266  2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.179639
```

What I want is a new dataframe, in which each of these dataframes represents a row, with its unique time value as the row's index, and the values of the id column as the column names. For example:

```
               time  13619782  12585081  12585081  10445552    360761  17162003  11387266
2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.149796  0.025866  0.031470  0.511263  0.030153  0.068670  0.182782
2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.171445  0.024932  0.030125  0.504263  0.027320  0.062276  0.179639
```

I did search for similar questions before posting but could not find anything, but my apologies if this has been asked/answered before. I'm relatively new to pandas/data analysis, and not even sure what this procedure would be called, and so wasn't sure what search terms to use other than "grouping/merging dataframes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `pivot` ([details](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)) after combining two dataframe (Assuming `df1` and `df2`) with `append`:

```
result_df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True).pivot(index='time', columns='id', values='prob')
result_df
```

Output:

```
id                   360761    10445552  11387266  12585081  12926892  \
time                                                                    
2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.030153  0.511263  0.182782  0.031470  0.025866   
2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.027320  0.504263  0.179639  0.030125  0.024932   

id                   13619782  17162003  
time                                     
2018-02-11 21:30:42  0.149796  0.068670  
2018-02-11 21:30:57  0.171445  0.062276
```